# Spark aggregate events from two different kafka topics orderd by timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

Assume a kafka system with the following two topics:

- created
- deleted

They are used to advertise the creation and deletion of items.

The structure of the events in kafka is JSON and the same for both topics:

```
{
  "id" : "a1cf621a-2a96-4b70-9dd6-3c54a2819eef"
  "timestamp": "2022-01-05T07:31:04.913000"
}
```

Now how it it possible with spark (scala) to accumulate the the deleted and created amounts such that we get a number of current items by timestamp.

Assume the following events in kafka

topic: **created**

```
{"id":"1","timestamp":"2022-01-01T00:00:00.000000"}
{"id":"2","timestamp":"2022-01-02T00:00:00.000000"}
```

topic: **deleted**

```
{"id":"2","timestamp":"2022-01-03T00:00:00.000000"}
{"id":"1","timestamp":"2022-01-04T00:00:00.000000"}
```

So this basically means:

- 2022-01-01: 1 item got created, total count of items is 1
- 2022-01-02: 1 item got created, total count of items is 2
- 2022-01-03: 1 item got deleted, total count of items is 1
- 2022-01-04: 1 item got deleted, total count of items is 0

The resulting output of the program should be the count of items per timestamp, as for example here:

```
----------------------------------------
| timestamp                    | count |
----------------------------------------
| 2022-01-01T00:00:00.000000   | 1     |
| 2022-01-02T00:00:00.000000   | 2     |
| 2022-01-03T00:00:00.000000   | 1     |
| 2022-01-04T00:00:00.000000   | 1     |
----------------------------------------
```

How can two topics be merged and the result ordered by timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read from both topics with `.option("subscribe", "created,deleted")`

Then you have a dataframe of both topics, and you can then parse the value for the timestamp, and should be able to sort by the timestamp, and aggregate/reduce the dataframe to get the output.

Alternatively, Kafka records already have a timestamp within them, which Spark returns as a column. So, you can change your producer design to have one topic, say `events`, remove the timestamp from the value, move the `id` to the record `key`, create events will have a non-null `value`, and delete events will have a `null` `value`.

Either way, you still need a [reducer function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#reduce-org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ReduceFunction-).

---

Or you can not use Spark, and with the proposed topic design, then creating a table in Kafka Streams / ksqlDB will already have the data you want. Not necessarily with timestamp information, but at least aggregate counts by ID or other value.

Comment: timestamp is there because this pipeline is also used for batch analysis of historical data, the timestamp corresponds to the timestamp of the event and not when it was sent to kafka.

Comment: In the Producer API, you can put the timestamp in any part of the record, but by default, Spark will only see when the record timestamp field, (which is when the record is created by the producer, "event time", not sent/written on the server, "log append time") , and not within the key, value or headers until you deserialize it

Comment: I am defining a schema so I am able to read this: `schema = new StructType().add("id", StringType, true).add("timestamp", TimestampType, true)`
What would you suggest to do in the case of historical data?

Comment: As mentioned [Spark includes the producer timestamp in the default schema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#reading-data-from-kafka). If you want historical data, just set `startingOffsets=earilest` as a config option and it'll read from the beginning of the topic(s)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am using `startingOffsets=earliest`